# Question about interpreting random forests

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm looking at energy consumption data for my thesis and I want to use a random forest model for predicting energy consumption using multiple features.

After I built, trained and validated my model, I want to interpret the data as much as possible.

Online I found that it is possible to look at feature importance to see which features were most influential in the outcome. Though my teacher asked me if there is a way to find out 'clusters of features which together lead to certain outcomes'. As an example he used (this example is totally made up):

*A high income generally leads to more consumption of energy, being a man leads generally to less consumption of energy, but being a man and having a high income might lead to more consumption than being a woman with a high income*

Is there any packages or functions that can find groups like this? So I guess instead of feature importance he is looking for something like 'group importance'? I'm not even sure anymore.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Tat said, have a look at SHAP: https://github.com/slundberg/shap

Comment: RF is a black box, do not count too much on feature importances unless you understand what they are. If you want to follow your teacher's advice, consider factor analysis with a respective R package `factorminer` (or do a bare PCA)